# How to make custom post taxonomy looks like regular categories?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, hierarchical

If I create a regular taxonomy for my custom post type, it behaves and looks like built-in tags taxonomy:

[image: regular taxonomy appearance]

And if I need to make it look like categories, I can add next `'hierarchical' => true` parameter to a `register_taxonomy` call and it works well except if I don't need hierarchical features.

[image: wp categories view]

How to make custom post taxonomy looks like category, but disable `hierarchical` option?

Comment: Using WordPress built-in functions you can not achieve this. One way you could do it is performing some CSS coding just within this page. If it fits you just say the word and I can post you the solution.

Comment: @filipecsweb, you meant to simply hide "parent category" selector? but there are some such fields under "add new category" page. If you can cover them all - would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

Within your functions.php:

```
function custom_admin_scripts( $hook ) {

    if ( $hook == 'post.php' && get_post_type() == 'your_custom_post_type_key' ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'your_custom_post_type_key', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/my_css_file.css', array(), false, 'all' );
    }

}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_admin_scripts' );
```

**Change `your_custom_post_type_key` to your custom post type key**
**Change `/my_css_file.css` to your real path towards your css file.**

Within your css file:

```
#{your_custom_taxonomy_key}-adder {
    display: none !important;
}
```

**Change `{your_custom_taxonomy_key}` to your custom taxonomy key.**

That CSS selector will hide, as aksed, the whole adder section.

This should do it.